# Modifying the file manager js to add a 'send' button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a 'send' botton to OpenCart's file manager by modifying its javascript [code](http://www.ritzcons.com/code/opencart156/admin/view/template/common/filemanager.tpl)

The aim is to send images by clicking a 'send' button rather double clicking the image, because in some Smartphones (such as Samsung Galaxy) the doubleclick doesn't work.

I added these lines to the end of line #98

```
< a id="send" class="button" style="background-image: url('view/image/filemanager/send.png');">SEND< /a>
```

And I copied the $('#column-right a').live('dblclick', function() at line #272
and pasted it into line #651 modified like this:

```
$('#send').bind('click', function() {
parent.$('#image').attr('value', 'data/' + $(this).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value'));
parent.$a('#dialog').dialog('close');
parent.$('#dialog').remove();
```

This code can't send the image to the filemanager. I'm guessing it's because the 'parent' of my send button  is different from the parent of the images. How can I make this button work?

The picture.
[image: the pic]

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

It was the $(this) variable which wasn't being evaluated properly.

It must have been

$('#column-right .selected')

Now it works as desired.